# Capturing UX using Factorial vignette studies

Tags: user-behavior, user-expectation, surveys

I am wondering if anyone has attempted to use Factorial vignette studies e.g., constant variable value vignettes or contrastive vignette techniques to explore UX for futuristic systems.  I am looking at using such an approach to understand end user expectations and behaviors given certain scenarios described in the vignettes when using robots to perform tasks.

I am looking for any potential examples of vignettes being used in UX.

Answer (score 1):

I feel like there are common research tools in UX that are similar. In the most basic sense, if a vignette study presents a person with a scenario, and then asks them some questions about how they feel about it, I'd say it's kind of like paper prototyping. In UX, you can use paper prototypes to quickly demonstrate and have a user explore a variety of interactions, and then solicit feedback afterwards.

This video has a pretty good example:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bq1rkVTZLtU

Comment: thanks for the response.  Relating the idea of factorial vignettes to paper prototyping got me thinking that the vignette survey approach is very similar to the use of personas